# rails ajax - check for new stories

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to set up a twitter-like feed. I would like the client to poll to see if there are new feeds based on a `@feeds` collection.

I thought I could do the check the latest feed the client has got, and make a query to obtain any feeds that occurred after that. However, that would restrict me to have the feeds ordered by time.

Is there any way to gather latest values in a collection? I eventually want to achieve something similar to facebook's top stories in the news feed.

Thanks!

Comment: You can store a `timestamp` value somewhere i.e. the time that you last requested to get latest feeds. And when you request next time, just fetch the feeds whose timestamp are greater than stored.

Comment: What's wrong with filtering by time, i.e. the `:created_at` or `:updated_at` column?